# How do I "exclude" an image from being used in the G+ Share Button/Box

Tags: image, google-plus, rich-snippets

When I share an article on my site (www.spoilertv.com), it picks up images such as my sites logo and favicon to use in the Google Plus share box

Screenshot

http://i47.tinypic.com/2zf5ymg.png

Is there a way I can exclude an image from being "picked up" by Google+  eg somehow using the itemprop="image" snippet item?

Answer (score 1):

The Google+ snippet fetcher makes a best guess when you do not specify an image using schema.org markup or Open Graph markup. You cannot explicitly exclude an image, but you can achieve the same effect by explicitly specifying a different image for your snippet :)

To specify a specific image you can add schema.org markup:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/trinket.jpg" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

or OpenGraph markup:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Example Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Example Description" />
```

You can learn more about how Google looks for images on your page on the [snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/).

Comment: Hey Jenny

Yep, I've been doing that already. The problem is that a lot of the images are generated on the fly so we can't inject the og:image stuff. Blogger does not automatically add the itemprop="name" into their code for image that are uploaded.

What I've done where possible is to change my images such as logos etc from raw <img's to css background-image:url () so that G+ does not "see" them :)

It works fairly well so I can have a default image of the site logo when no images exist in a post and if they do exist it picks up the first article image.

Comment: Thanks for the update :)  I understand better now. The CSS background trick will indeed work, but it's tied to implementation details of the 'best guess' feature and might change later without warning. But, it sounds like something will need to change in blogger to support this :)